# detecting the delimiter without using potential delimiters in PHP

Tags: php, delimiter

I need to use a function in PHP that detect a delimiter of a file using 2 parameters:

the file handle and an array of the expected header values.

Can someone please help me in writing the function or using a similar existing function that use the header of the file and match it with the expected header values to detect the file delimiter without using an array of potential delimiters.

Thank you

Comment: What are you calling a "file delimiter"?

Comment: Will values always/never/possibly be encapsulated in quotes?

Comment: yes they can be or not encapculated in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $col1 = 'name';
    $enc = '"';
    $line = '"name";"company";"email"';

    $delimiter = substr($line, (substr($line, 0, 1) == $enc ? (strlen($col1)+2) : strlen($col1)), 1);
    echo $delimiter;

?>
```

**Output**

```
;
```

This first checks if the 1st character in `$line` is `"`. If there is no `"`, it substrings 1 character with a starting position of the length of `$col1`. If there are `"`, it substrings 1 character with a starting position of the length of `$col1` +2 (for each of the `"`)

Comment: Thank you Danny, it is really helpful I really forgot to accept answers in the past I was unfortunely looking at answers and closing the page, Thank you :)

Comment: @lollos90 Edited my answer - there's no need for an array of headers since it only checks the first column.

Comment: ok Danny, but I am working with users uploaded files were not all the headers can be used and the order can be different, thanks :)

Comment: @lollos90 Then neither the previous version of the PHP, nor this version can be used. The code would need serious modification for that functionality to work.

Comment: yes sure, I am working on this using the string functions, but I am really facing problems with presence of enclosure characeters, do you know a way that can help in this, Thank you:)

Comment: @lollos90 I updated my answer. You can now set the encapsulation character in `$enc`

Comment: ok Danny thanks but I think this carachter depends on the uploaded file and may be different based on the type of the file